# Unsure What it Means by "} expected"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small thing in Unity for my Game Design class, and I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue and test out what I've done so far. This is my first piece of code so I'm stumped, and even looking at people who've had similar problems hasn't helped me figure anything out. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Motion : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.D) ){
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed)
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) {
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.left * speed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) {
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.down * speed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) ){
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.up * speed);
        }
    } **} expected**
```

I would ask my teacher but he's out for Spring Break and I'm trying to get some make up work done. Sorry if this is a dumb question and thanks to everyone who helps in advance!

Comment: I suppose it´s just the end of your class, isn´t it?

Comment: You're missing `)`'s at the end of some of the `if` conditions.

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket of your class. The last bracket in your code closes the `Update` method, but you also need to close the declaration of `Motion`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Motion : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.D)){
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.left * speed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.down * speed);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            Transform.Translate (Vector2.up * speed);
        }
    }
//dont forget to close the namespace tag(uncomment the next line if needed)
//}
```

Comment: It's not about a namespace. In the code you can see a class only. And it has an opening curly brace but doesn't have a closing one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply brace matching as a syntax of C# programming language.

In your case, end brace of class is missed. So compiler gives that error message.

more info:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33378/whats-your-method-of-not-forgetting-the-end-brackets-parentheses)

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33378/whats-your-method-of-not-forgetting-the-end-brackets-parentheses